# When scraping data from website and writing to a csv file, only the last row was written to the file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am using python and beautiful soup to extract data from a web page and it works. The problem is that its not inserting all the values to the csv file. Like if I extract 10 data values than only the 10th data value goes to csv file, the 9th one doesn't. All 10 data values show up on the terminal but not in csv file.

## import libraries

```
import csv

import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



# specify the url
quote_page = "https://www.cardekho.com/Hyundai/Gurgaon/cardealers"
#quote_page = input("Enter Data Source Here : ")
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)



# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")


# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
delrname = soup.find_all('div', class_='deleadres')
for name in delrname:
    dname = name.find('div', class_="delrname").text # name
    print(dname)
for address in delrname:
    dadres = address.find('p').text
    print(dadres)
for mobile in delrname:
    dmobile = mobile.find('div', class_="clearfix").text
    print(dmobile)
for email in delrname:
    demail = email.find('div', class_="mobno").text
    print(demail)





#exorting data into csv file....
with open('result.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    data = [line for line in r]
with open('result.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['NAME','ADDRES','MOBILE','EMAIL'])
    w.writerow([dname,dadres,dmobile,demail])**strong text**
```

Answer (score 1):

When you assign values in a for-loop, you replace the former value. So outside the loop, you will be left with the final value.

```
for number in 1, 2, 3:
    print(number) # prints 1, then 2, then 3
print(number) # prints only 3, since that was the final value.
```

In your script, use a single for-loop to both extract values and write data rows to the csv.

```
with open('result.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['NAME','ADDRES','MOBILE','EMAIL']) # write header once
    entries = soup.find_all('div', class_='deleadres')
    for entry in entries: # loop over all `.deleadres` elements
        dname = entry.find('div', class_="delrname").text
        dadres = entry.find('p').text
        dmobile = entry.find('div', class_="clearfix").text
        demail = entry.find('div', class_="mobno").text
        w.writerow([dname,dadres,dmobile,demail]) # write data rows for each entry
```

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in my query. It was very helpful, and finally it got my problem solved. –

Comment: You are welcome. On stack overflow, you don't need to write a comment to say thanks. Instead vote up (or down) and accept the most useful answer. Use comments to ask for clarifications or add detail. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: i will keep it in my mind. actually i am beginner here.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is that you are only saving the last value from the loop, hence you are not getting all the values.

Another way to do it:

1) Add your values from the loop to the list

2) Add values from the list to the CSV

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)
# CREATE NEW LISTS
dname_list = list()
dadres_list = list()
dmobile_list = list()
demail_list = list()


# parse the html using beautiful soup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")

# APPEND TO THE LIST
# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
delrname = soup.find_all('div', class_='deleadres')
for name in delrname:
    dname = name.find('div', class_="delrname").text # name
    print(dname)
    dname_list.append(dname)
for address in delrname:
    dadres = address.find('p').text
    print(dadres)
    dadres_list.append(dadres)
for mobile in delrname:
    dmobile = mobile.find('div', class_="clearfix").text
    print(dmobile)
    dmobile_list.append(dmobile)
for email in delrname:
    demail = email.find('div', class_="mobno").text
    print(demail)
    demail_list.append(demail)


#exorting data into csv file....
with open('result.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    data = [line for line in r]
with open('result.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    w.writerow(['NAME','ADDRES','MOBILE','EMAIL'])
    # TRAVERSE THROUGH THE LIST
    for i in range(len(dname)):
        try:
            w.writerow([dname_list[i],dadres_list[i],dmobile_list[i],demail_list[i]])
        except IndexError:
            print('')
```

PS: Haken's answer is a better way of doing it. I just thought of letting you know another way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me in my query. It was very helpful, and finally it got my problem solved.